# World Map Using Highchart in R

Tags: r, highcharts, rworldmap

I am analyzing the covid data from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tunguz/data-on-covid19-coronavirus). I am trying to plot world map with different scenarios such as total cases, new cases, total vaccinated etc.

Am using this syntax:

```
covid<-fread(covid_data.csv)

I have renamed the column name 'location' to 'region' for joining with other world map data.

country_count<-covid %>% 
  group_by(region, total_cases, iso_code) %>% 
  summarise(count=n()) %>% 
  as.data.frame
  
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, df = country_count, value = "total_cases", joinBy = "iso_code") %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_db()) %>% 
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_title(text = "Total Cases", style = list(fontSize = "25px")) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_google()) %>%
  hc_credits(enabled = TRUE,text = "Sources: WHO", style = list(fontSize = "10px"))
```

The map is populating very slowly and I want to fill the world map with color hue based on the number of total cases. But am not sure how to populate this using **hc_colorAxis**.

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this.

Any tweaks that could load maps faster is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Hi, could you recreate this example in JavaScript? I suppose you need to put this total case in [colorAxis.max](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis.max).

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Unfortunately am not familiar how to do it.

Comment: You can check this [documentation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/highcharter/html/hc_colorAxis.html) looks helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing the wrong way. Instead of iso_code, I should join by name. This fixed the issue.